# Box shadow not showing on both sides

Tags: html, css

I use this css code for box shadow but I get only on the top and bottom 
[Look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKzHv.png)

```
div#blog-pager {
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);}
```

this css style don't have shadow style

```
#blog-pager{background:#fff;clear:both;width:auto;padding:20px;line-height:normal;position:relative;display:block;text-align:right;overflow:visible;margin:20px 0 5px 0}
```

I don't know if this code above affect the code I added

This is my blog : [Blog](http://t4geeks.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add margin:2px to #blog-pager. because the #main-wrapper have `overflow: hidden;`

```
#blog-pager {
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
margin: 2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to change your css a bit

```
div#blog-pager {
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
```

**Each value in box-shadow means**

`first : offset-x`
`second: offset-y`
`third : blur-radius`
`fourth: spread-radius`
`last: color`

For more information [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add some spread radius as 4th attribute to the box-shadow

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```